# Laravel relative temporary signed route signature always invalid

Tags: php, laravel

This is how I'm generating the signed route:

```
return env('APP_URL') . URL::temporarySignedRoute('file_url', now()->addMinutes(5), ['path' => $this->attributes['attachment']], false);
```

This is the named route definition:

```
Route::get('file-url', 'FileController@getFileUrl')->name('file_url');
```

In the following function, it is saying the signature is not valid:

```
public function getFileUrl(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasValidSignature()) {
        $path = $request->get('path');
        return Storage::disk('cln_local')->download($path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Prepending `env('APP_URL').` will make this not work here. *I think* the signature generated must match the exact URL returned by  `URL::temporarySignedRoute` and you concatenating the APP_URL might result in a mismatching signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created your temporary signed route as a relative route (fourth parameter `$absolute` set to `false`). Because of this, you have to validate the route as a relative route.

You can either pass `false` to the `hasValidSignature()` method, or you can use the `hasValidRelativeSignature()` method.

```
if ($request->hasValidSignature(false)) {

// or

if ($request->hasValidRelativeSignature()) {
```